# How sprintf works in PHP?

Tags: php, printf

I am a little bit confused.
I have php code:

```
echo "Hashnum='".$Hashnum."'\n";    //it prints:    Hashnum='-308274319'
$HashStr = sprintf('%u', $Hashnum) ;
$length = strlen($HashStr);         //it prints:    HashStr='3986692977'
```

I expected last command print the same number, but it prints another. Why?
How sprintf function works?

Comment: Title: *How fprintf works*. Content: *sprintf*. Tags: *php sprintf*. Makes no sense.

Comment: [If only there were a PHP.net manual entry for the `sprintf` function…](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

Comment: read this http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Comment: `fprintf($fp, "Hello %s", "World")` where `$fp` is pointer to fopen.

Answer (score 1):

`%u` is an **unsigned** integer. By definition, unsigned integers are only positive numbers, since they do not have a "sign" (a bit denoting whether the number is positive or negative). By necessity the results cannot be the same if you interpret a negative signed number into an unsigned one.

Comment: Well, but unsigned integer would be "308274319"

Comment: No, because it's interpreting the *bit representation* of the number. In signed integers, the first bit denotes the sign. In unsigned integers, all bits denote values. So the bits are interpreted entirely differently.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is the way signed numbers are encoded in binary: It's called [Two's Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

The following formula describes how the bits (the value of the *i*-th bit is given by *a<sub>i</sub>*, which is either zero or one) in a two's complement number are interpreted:

[image]

*N* is 32 because PHP uses 32-bit integer arithmetic.

If the sign bit is set, i.e. *a<sub>31</sub>* = 1, then *2<sup>32 - 1</sup> = 2<sup>31</sup>* is subtracted from the result, as indicated by: *-a<sub>N-1</sub>2<sup>N-1</sup>*.

If the bits are interpreted as an unsigned number, and the "sign bit" is set to 1 (which it is in your case), *2<sup>31</sup>* would be *added* instead:

[image]

This is why you see a difference of 2<sup>32</sup>, that is two times 2<sup>31</sup>.

*-308274319 + 2<sup>32</sup> = 3986692977*

Interpretation of unsigned numbers:

Comment: @punk `i` is the index of a bit: `a_i` denotes the i-th bit, i.e. `a_0` is the least-significant bit that determines if a number is even or odd. Does that help?

Comment: @punk Also, take a look at the [Σ/Sigma/summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation) notation.

Comment: well answered, can you tell me a perfect reason why linux converts `char` data type to its numeric representation (ASCII) value.I only know that working with `int` is a better and faster way to manipulate strings.

Comment: @punk It doesn't convert, it's a question of interpretation. Deep down, everything is stored as numbers. You should probably [**ask your own question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)